# Is there any option in iOS to change iPhone language from my app?

Tags: ios, localization

I am using `Localization` and it is working fine for my app. I want to change iPhone language. I mean all apps and iPhone language should be Change.

Comment: would you be happy if some app on your iPhone permanently change the language?

Answer (score 3):

No. The user have to do it via Settings

Comment: +1 to this answer. Implementing an in-app language switcher is not recommended. If you want this as a feature, you should file a bug report at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)